# webpack with babel-preset-env "last 2 versions" with internet explorer

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

Maybe I am a little naive. The README on babel-preset-env

https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env

says:

> A Babel preset that compiles ES2015+ down to ES5 by automatically determining the Babel plugins and polyfills you need based on your targeted browser or runtime environments.

And yet, IE11 chokes on backticks and promies because webpack/babel neither transpiles down backtick templates to regular strings nor does it come up with a promise polyfill.

I am using webpack 3.4.1 and babel-core 6.2.5.

What is it that I am not getting here?

This is the ***use*** section of my webpack config for babel:

```
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          [
            'env',
            {
              targets: {
                browsers: [
                  'last 2 versions'
                ]
              },
              modules: false
            }
          ]
        ],
        plugins: [
          'transform-runtime',
          'syntax-dynamic-import'
        ]
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I suspect it has something to do with treeshaking maybe

Comment: @Jax Cavalera

No, unfortunately not. Since then I've made a ton changes to my webpack file/s, which has/ve grown quite big. Eventually I got it working and I wish I knew why. I am not really happy with webpack. Each project I am starting, I am running into new – sometimes even old – problems. It's a little disappointing.

However, at the moment I am looking into parcel js: https://parceljs.org

It seems to be somewhat simpler for a change.

Comment: I worked out why it was broken for me, the developer of stripAnsi has arrow functions which don't transpile and webpack-dev-server uses that so what you get is a problem where browsers like ie11 just die, fix for me was to specify using version 2.9.7 of webpack-dev-server which works.  As for the whole promise not working i ended up using ProvidePlugin with es6-promise-promise which did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was bashing my head against the wall for 2 days, because babel wasn't transpiling anything at all! Finally I found the culprit: it was that babel-loader [wasn't reading](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/552) `.babelrc` at all. After migrating to [babel.config.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/configuration.html#babelconfigjs) babel-loader now correctly uses the specified preset and polyfills.

My working `babel.config.js` config for `@babel/core 7`, `@babel/present-env 7`, `@babel/polyfill 7`, `babel-loader 8`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);

return {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/env', {
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```